# Google Map API as an actor to my system

Tags: api, uml, use-case, google-maps

My system will deal with Google map API to locate user's location after his/her request.

I am drawing the use case diagram and wondering if "Google Map API" should be an external actor to my system or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use cases](http://agilemodeling.com/style/useCaseDiagram.htm) represent the goals/intents that the system is required to  achieve.

[Actors](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-actor.html) represent users and external systems that interact with the system for the purpose of the use case.  "*Google MAP*" could be such a system.  But as it is only contributing to the use case for the purpose of supporting the goals of other actors, it would be [secondary actor](https://blogs.oracle.com/oum/use-case-actors-primary-versus-secondary).

**Important remark  1:** presenting such a system on a use-case diagram makes sense only if the involvement of the external system is relevant from the point of view of the use-case goals (i.e. it's part of the user requirements).  Technical infrastructures, such as cloud databases and similar external supporting systems should not be presented on a use case diagram: they are only technical solutions to the requirements.

**Important remark 2:**  on the use-case you would have the external system, which is "*Google MAP*" and not "*Google MAP API*".  The ***API*** is a technical artifact that specifies how to interact with the remote ***service***. You could this interface  in a [component diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/component-diagrams.html), or in a [deployment diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/deployment-diagrams-overview.html),

Answer (score 0):

> ... wondering if "Google Map API" should be an external actor to my system or not.

UML not being a methodology, you can decide. [Craig Larman's UML approach](http://www.craiglarman.com/wiki/downloads/applying_uml/larman-ch6-applying-evolutionary-use-cases.pdf) proposes using the external service as *supporting actor*:

[image]

It might be interesting to abstract it to a Mapping System (rather than Google Maps), since this is a service provided by Apple, Google, Microsoft, etc. Each has likely a different API, but you could develop an adapter interface, so the core aspect of your internal system wouldn't need to know the details. Larman's book does a great job to explain how that could work.